# How to put an Application's value as a variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a counter that updates itself everytime the page loads. I want to use that counter's value as a variable in javascript so that I could use it. How do I do this?

```
    if (Application["counter"] == null)
        {
            Application["counter"] = 0;
        }
        if (Application["counter"] != null)
        {
            if (Request.Form["sub1"]==null)
            {
                Response.Write("<script>alert('You must Enter Number')</script>");
            }
            if (Request.Form["sub1"] != null)
            {
                Application["counter"] =(int)Application["counter"]+ 1;
                Response.Write(Application["counter"]);
            }
        }
```

this is the code for the counter in the cs page.
Whenever I go to write Javascript and try to save it as a variable it gives me an error: Error 16   Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement.

```
var y=<%Application["counter"];>%;
```

Comment: `var y = <%= Application["counter"] %>;` You have 2 typos in the same line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the server side code, you can use it like below. Just a recommendation. And for front end side, you have typos.

```
// Server side code - Correct usage

if (Application["counter"] == null) {
  Application["counter"] = 0;
}

// there's no need to check Application["counter"] after the code above

if (Request.Form["sub1"] == null)
{
  Response.Write("<script>alert('You must Enter Number')</script>");
}
// also, you can use else in here instead of another if, because there isn't any other condition.
else { 
  Application["counter"] = (int)Application["counter"] + 1;
  Response.Write(Application["counter"]);
}

// JS Code

var y = <%= Application["counter"] %>;
```